# How to get array value from JSON if passing Xpath through a String using Slurper

Tags: json, groovy, soapui

Json Response after parsing

```
String Json= consents:[[id:740, duration:FixedPeriod, status:Active]], [[id:740, duration:FixedPeriod, status:Active]] [[id:740, duration:FixedPeriod, status:Active]] 

String Xpath = consents.id[0]
```

My Code as below

```
json = slurper.parseText(resvalue1.toString())  

 String[] XpathSplit = arSpRt[1].split(["\\."]) // xpath [0] is xpath od field in response
                    log.info "Xpath[1]"+ arSpRt[1]          // xpth[1] expected value of string


                log.info "XpathSplit  " + XpathSplit

                        for(j=0;j<XpathSplit.length;j++){
                        log.info "XpathSplit[j]  "+XpathSplit[j].toString()
                        json = json.(XpathSplit[j])                         
                             log.info "ActualValue ####" +json                      
                            }
```

So if I put only `"consents.id"` from a string  its returning me all ids in consent array but I want `consents.id[0]` as first vale but its returning `null`

Comment: don't know why are you providing xpath like this. you can put straightly like `json.consents.id[0]`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46551949/how-to-get-key-from-arraylist-nested-in-json-using-groovy-and-change-its-value/46553716#46553716

Comment: Because I need to provide Xpath from a variable.

Comment: Can you post the JSON document you're trying to parse?

Comment: Hi @craigcaulfield, I have already provided the sample above in the questions please find the same below.                                                                         String Json= consents:[[id:740, duration:FixedPeriod, status:Active]], [[id:740, duration:FixedPeriod, status:Active]] [[id:740, duration:FixedPeriod, status:Active]] 

String Xpath = consents.id[0]